# Apply class to TD if it has a rowSpan attribute

Tags: jquery

Looking for a really simple way in jQuery to add a class to a TD when it has the rowspan attribute.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I think this would work:

```
$('td[rowspan]').addClass('className');
```

This uses the [Has Attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/).

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(function(){      
              jQuery('td[rowspan]')      //select all TD's with attribute=rowspan
              .addClass('class_name');   // now add class to them
});
```

//